# Cordova inAppBrowser with phonegap build not working

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build, inappbrowser

I am trying to open external links in the inAppBrowser in Cordova using Phonegap Build. My links are dynamically added based on results pulled from the database, and I am using this code in my initializer:

```
document.onclick = (e) ->
  e = e or window.event
  element = e.target or e.srcElement
  if element.tagName == 'A'
    cordova.inAppBrowser.open element.href, '_blank', 'location=yes'
    return false
    # prevent default action and stop event propagation
  return
```

This doesn't seem to do anything in my compiled app though, it just opens the link in the viewport of the app and then I have to exit the app to get back to my application.

This is the entry in my `config.xml` file

```
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser"/>
```

Also, in my Javascript console on development, `cordova.inAppBrowser` is undefined. I am fairly new to Cordova/Phonegap development, what am I doing wrong to use plugins/the inAppBrowser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change your

```
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser"/>
```

to

```
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" source="npm"/>
```

You are using an old version of the plugin and `cordova.InAppBrowser.open` function was added recently, in previous version you have to open the inAppBrowser with `window.open` instead

Comment: I had found this on the Phonegap Build support community already, but thank you for answering here, I forgot about it! To add to your answer, I was also misspelling `InAppBrowser`. It has a capital "I".

Answer (score 0):

in PhoneGap build, after version 3.7.0, you can not open any link in your application if you do not use this plugin:

```
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" source="npm"/>
```

add this code to the config.xml file and then you can use external links in your app